# A problem with Mertens Theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, zeta-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant

According to [Mertens Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensTheorem.html)
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } (\frac{1}{ln(p_n)} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_k}})=1.781072\dots$$

so we can say
$$ 1.78 \ ln(p_n) \sim  \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_k}}$$

As $p_n \sim n \ ln(n)$ I tried to plot both side in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rivzb7kl5u) [image]

but it seems that they are not going to be similar I tried other number like 6.6 and it was better
but why such things happened ?

Comment: In the product , $p_n$ must instead be $p_k$.

Comment: The range in the plot is very small. Try much larger numbers $n$ , for so small numbers , we won't get a very good approximation.